# chrome (Android) - input type=time under rtl language - reversed order for input

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, input, right-to-left

Using input field type='time' - when open the page with chrome on android and the phone language is set to Hebrew,  the field is displayed fine, but when I try to set value, the inner fields are in reversed order (i.e. the hours in the right side, the minutes on the left).  Is it solvable?

Simplest code to reproduce:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            input type=time example
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='time' value='13:55:00'>
    </body>
</html>
```

link to screenshot: http://www.ddc.co.il/wordpress_heb/demos/stam_input_time.jpg

Comment: Hey @guy-dafny , I would like to know if you solved this issue somehow. I encountered it myself just now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OmerBonfil, Sorry but unfortunately I hadn't.